# How can I improve WPF drawing application?

Tags: wpf, performance, image, bmp

The belows are my code to draw image as background of border object.

```
   void DrawImage()
   {     
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage chartBitmapImage = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        chartBitmapImage.BeginInit();
        chartBitmapImage.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
        chartBitmapImage.EndInit();
        imageBrush.ImageSource = chartBitmapImage;            
        aBorder.Background = imageBrush;
        ...
   }
```

The above DrawImage() method is called every seconds.
All operation is work well but too slow.

I want to improve the performance.
Is there any point to improve this ?
Maybe, I guess any bmp image processing method is betther solution than I used.
Help me...

Comment: Is your image changing every time you draw it - if not, why not save and reuse it (or only update it when it does change)?

Comment: my image changing every seconds.

Comment: Does it change on a cycle (so you've got a limited number of different images), or is each image distinct?

Answer (score 0):

1. Profile the code to find the slowest line of code.
2. Make that part go faster.
3. Repeat until performance is acceptable.